# Turn density impact on B Flux

Tags: electromagnetism, inductance

I am messing around with electromagnets and I am actually making my own winding them by hand. The equations that are used to calculate magnetic field strength do not really have a geometry term in them, outside the number of turns. Am I to interpret that as how the coil is packed does not matter. So neatness, thickness or length of the windings do not matter? As long as I get the turns and amperage I should roughly have the same strength.

This is pertinent because I have a couple gauges of wire and if I can give myself more room by spreading out the coiling and use a lower gauge.

Background info - I am making Helmholtz coils that are 60mm in diameter. To increase the strength I am adding iron cores to both rings. I am hoping to manipulate a magnetic plate in the middle that will press down on things. Ideally I would like to make a field with a strength of roughly 1000-3000 Gauss.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: When you see $B_\text{int} = \mu_0 n I$ you are looking at an expression for an idealized, dense, unifrom, infinite solenoid. If you wind it loosely or irregularly you are loosing the "dense" and/or "uniform" idealizations (as well as not actually have infinite length). How big a deal that is depnds on how loose and how irregular your winding is.

Comment: @dmckee so assuming neat coils. If I doubled length of the coil bobbin would the field drop off by half